# how to show a viewcontroller as slideOut menu bar?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

In my project I create a class for menu list and I want too show that menu list through pan gesture and bar button form multiple viewController class, using call my baseViewController class.

Attaching code which I written in base viewController class:

```
-(void)ActionMenu:(id)sender {
CGRect destination = self.navigationController.view.frame;
if (destination.origin.x > 0) {
    destination.origin.x = 0;
} else {
    destination.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width -60;
}
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.navigationController.view.frame = destination;
}];
}
```

by this way I can slide the view but cann't show menu [![enter image 
description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2YuO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2YuO.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2YuO.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FEQa.png  want to show menu in the replace of black screen area. and the menu page is...[image: which I want to show]

please help me... Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to present a menu like this ? https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Comment: I don't want to use any third party

Comment: Do you use interface builder for your project, or is it pure code?